# node.js Q promises does not propagate exception through rejection handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I am using [requestify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requestify) to make some HTTP requests. The module internally makes use other modules such as HTTP, socket etc. It also makes use of Q promises.

The modules used by requestify can asynchronously throw exceptions (e.g. ECONNREFUSED can be thrown by the socket module). Whenever an exception is thrown, the control flow breaks away to my process's generic uncaught-exception handler and does not get propagated to the promise's error/reject handler.

the code below is a sample code, which represents the issue.

Question - Is it possible for for me to handle such exceptions through the Q promise's rejection handler?

```
// sample code
var _inspect = require('util').inspect;
var _q = require('q');

function handle_uncaught_exception(ex) {
  console.log(" Uncaught Exception: " + _inspect(ex));
  process.exit(2);
}
process.on('uncaughtException', handle_uncaught_exception);

function foo_3rd_party_code() {
  var d = _q.defer();
  setTimeout(
    function () {
      throw new Error("TEST_EXCEPTION");
    },
    1000
  );
  return d.promise;
}

foo_3rd_party_code()
  .then(
    function (val) {
      console.log("Promise Fullfilled: " + _inspect(val));
      process.exit(0);
    },
    function (err) {
      // it would be nice to see the TEST_EXCEPTION here.
      console.log("Promise Rejected: " + _inspect(err));
      process.exit(1);
    }
  );
```

Comment: What if you got multiple promises running concurrently? How would your uncaught exception handler know which of them is to be rejected?

Comment: A more reasonable approach would be to fix (or, get fixed) the third-party code (through appropriate processes) so that it doesn't `throw` exceptions but reports the errors.

Comment: thanks. have asked the module owner to look at the possibility to catch the exception and convert that through reject().

Answer (score 3):

`foo_3rd_party_code` can't catch or handle the exception because it can't see it. You must use the `reject` method of the promise for that.

```
function foo_3rd_party_code() {
  var d = _q.defer();
  setTimeout(
    function () {
      d.reject(new Error("TEST_EXCEPTION"));
    },
    1000
  );
  return d.promise;
}
```

Comment: It is not my code. and the exception is buried deep into 3rd party code. I have send a request to the module owner to look at the possible enhancement.